# Maven: How can I use a separate file specifying developer-specific config?

Tags: java, maven

`Database URL`, `username`, `password` vary in our developer team. Now I want to use this way and set up the profile in `pom.xml`:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>local</id>

    <properties>
      <db.url>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/xx?sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false</db.url>
      <db.mysql.username>xx</db.mysql.username>
      <db.mysql.password>xx</db.mysql.password>
      <serverBaseUrl>http://127.0.0.1:8080</serverBaseUrl>
    </properties>

    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>

  </profile>

  <profile>
    <id>test</id>

    <properties>
      <db.url>jdbc:mysql://xx/xx?sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false</db.url>
      <db.mysql.username>xx</db.mysql.username>
      <db.mysql.password>xx</db.mysql.password>
      <serverBaseUrl>http://xx:8133</serverBaseUrl>
    </properties>

    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>

  </profile>
</profiles>
```

I want properties like `db.mysql.username` be set in a separate file named `developer-specific-config.properties`, and create a file name `developer-specific-config.properties.example` to tell other developers how to use. Also, I'd like to add `developer-specific-config.properties` to gitignore so that it won't be traced.

How to finish it?

Comment: Use filters in maven where you can specify your different configuration in each profile's own file and use -P profilename to load appropriate config at the time of building your project

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Do you mean adding this `resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>`? I have already set it up.

Comment: I believe what you want to do is, carry your profile specific information in their own separate files, and at the time of building the project, depending upon the profile you give, it should pick the info accordingly. Right? If you want this, I can give you examples in more detail.

Comment: Yes you are going right. You also need to declare filters like this <filters>
   <filter>src/main/filters/filter-${env}.properties</filter>
  </filters> and then specify different filter files that you need to use while building your project

Comment: "Do you want to carry your profile specific information in their own separate files?" No exactly. I want to carry developer specific information in their own separate files, not profile specific

Comment: Call it profile or developer, I think that's just a label. Like one of the profile could be prod or dev or staging. In same way you can have additional profiles like guo1 or guo2 etc

Comment: This is the purpose of `settings.xml`.